# Vapor error on drop.client.get, Sockets Error: Failed trying to connect to

Tags: ubuntu-16.04, swift4, vapor

I'm trying to deploy my Vapor app to an ubuntu (16.04) server, but when I run it I'm getting an error

`Sockets Error: Failed trying to connect to http://www.c-bike.com.tw:80`

The app runs fine on my local server and on Vapor Cloud. This happens on this line of code

`let bikesResponse = try drop.client.get("http://www.c-bike.com.tw/xml/stationlistopendata.aspx")`

Does anyone have any idea?

I tried `curl http://www.c-bike.com.tw/xml/stationlistopendata.aspx` and that worked fine, so it's not blocked. And as mentioned, the app works when I run it locally on my Mac.

Thank you!

Comment: Have you got a local network server you could try the get(...) on? If so, does it still fail? Presumably, when you do the command line curl, it's the same user as when you run the vapor app?

Comment: Hi Nick, I have edited the code and do a `get()` on another address such as bbc.com, and that worked perfectly, so it seems to only have a problem with  this particular address. Yes, `curl` was using the same user as `vapor run serve`

Comment: Hi. I tried putting it as test route in one of my projects and after about 20s it returns with no output. Putting bbc.com works for me too. I'm not getting any errors when c-bike fails though. I tried the curl from command line on Ubuntu 16.04 as well and got the same results (i.e. nothing!). Can't think of anything else. Sorry.

Comment: Hey Nick, thanks for taking the time to look into it! :) So strange that it works on macOS but not ubuntu.